# BCEWithLogitsLoss: Trying to get binary output for predicted label as a tensor, confused with output layer

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

Each element of my dataset has a multi-label tensor like `[1, 0, 0, 1]` with varying combinations of `1's` and `0's`. In this scenario, since I have 4 tensors, I have the output layer of my neural network to be 4. In doing so with BCEWithLogitsLoss, I obtain an output tensor like `[3, 2, 0, 0]` when I call model(inputs) which is in the range of (0, 3) as I specified with the output layer to have 4 output neurons. This does not match the format of what the target is expected to be, although when I change the number of output neurons to 2, I get a shape mismatch error. What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) you make a 1D prediction per output binary label.
In your example, you have 4 binary labels to predict, and therefore, your model outputs 4d vector, each entry represents the prediction of one of the binary labels.

Using `BCEWithLogitsLoss` you *implicitly* apply Sigmoid to your outputs:

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class.

Therefore, if you want to get the predicted *probabilities* of your model, you need to add a [`torch.sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sigmoid.html#torch.sigmoid) on top of your prediction. The [`sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sigmoid.html#torch.sigmoid) function will convert your predicted *logits* to probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing
`y_preds = model(input)`

but your loss/ criterion was `BCEWithLogitsLoss`, then the output, that is, `y_pred` is the logit. Logit can be negative or positive. Logit is z, where z = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... wn*xn.

So, for your predictions while using BCEWithLogitsLoss, you need to pass this output (`y_pred`) through a sigmoid layer (For this you can create a small function which returns `1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(x,w)))`. And then you would be all set :)

Hope this helps!!!